# Cannot access parent element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I figured out my previous question but now I'm trying to change the parent element.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var itemheight = 30;

    //When mouse rolls over
    $("li").mouseover(function() {
        var numitems = $(this).children().children().length;
        var newheight = numitems * itemheight + 18;
        $(this).stop().animate({
            height: newheight
        }, {
            queue: false,
            duration: 600,
            easing: 'swing'
        });
    });

    //When mouse is removed
    $("li").mouseout(function() {
        //change totalheight back to 18;
        $(this).stop().animate({
            height: '18px'
        }, {
            queue: false,
            duration: 600,
            easing: 'swing'
        });
    });

    //When mouse rolls over
    $("li ul li").mouseover(function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({
            height: 30
        });
        $(this).parent().parent().animate({
            backgroundColor: '#D52716'
        });
    });

    //When mouse is removed
    $("li ul li").mouseout(function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({
            height: '18px'
        }, {
            queue: false,
            duration: 600,
            easing: 'swing'
        })
    });

});
```

Question 1:  What is the functional difference (if any) between using > and .children() ?

The problem I'm having is with the third function.  I cannot get the grandparent i.e. top level menu to change.  Ultimately I want to change its height but I'm playing with the background color to make it easier right now.  Thing is that even if I change that line to

```
$(this).animate({backgroundColor:'#D52716'});
```

Nothing happens.  It's like it's not calling that function at all.
Question 2:  What am I doing wrong?

Here's my HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<title>Basic Menu System</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="menuanim.js"></script>
<link href="menujq.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
</HEAD>

<BODY>
<ul id=topmenu>
<li class="green">First item</li>
<li class="yellow">Second item
    <ul>
    <li>Submenu 
    <ul>
        <li>Tiertiary01</li>
        <li>Tiertiary02</li>        
        <li>Tiertiary03</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Submenu2</li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
</div>  <!-- End maincontent -->

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

And my CSS

/* Top menu with dropdowns */

```
#topmenu, #topmenu ul {
list-style: none;
text-align: center;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}


#topmenu li {
text-align:center;
overflow:hidden;
float: left;
font-size: 12px;
font-weight: bold;
border: 3px solid #A0A0A0;
width: 150px;
height: 18px;
padding: 3px;
color: #000000;
}


.green{background:#6AA63B;}
.yellow{background:#FBC700;}
.red{background:#D52100;}
.purple{background:#5122B4;}
.blue{background:#0292C0;}
/****************************************************/

/* Second level */
#topmenu li ul {
display: none;
}

#topmenu li:hover > ul {
display: block;
position: relative;
left: -6px;
top: 7px;
}

#topmenu li ul li {     /* All attributes are inherited */
}

/*****************************************************/
```

Comment: Show your html for this

Comment: Did you include https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color or similar? Also take a look at CSS transitions.

Answer (score 0):

The first question can be [tested in a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8bhRB/), the console output of which shows that functionally they act the same. If you're more used to using selectors compatible with both jQuery and CSS, you might choose the [Child Selector ("parent > child")](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) form over the [`.children`](http://api.jquery.com/children/) convention.

Your second question can be answered with a quote straight from the [`jQuery.animate()` docs](http://api.jquery.com/animate/):

> All animated properties should be animated to a single numeric value,
>   except as noted below; most properties that are non-numeric cannot be
>   animated using basic jQuery functionality (For example, `width`, `height`,
>   or left can be animated but `background-color` cannot be, unless the
>   `jQuery.Color()` plugin is used).

In your example code, you haven't indicated that you've included the `jQuery.Color()` plugin, so that should be where your problem lies.

Comment: Ignoring the plugin for a second, changing the line to  $(this).parent().parent().animate({height:'1000px'}); doesn't change the height of the grandparent i.e. top level menu item.

Answer (score 0):

### Question 1:

Yeah, you can make child selections multiple ways, but one is easier to read than the other.  `.children()` is more readable that `.find('> *')`, though they do the same thing.

### Question 2:

[esqew's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25002588/790075) is probably what you want.  You also may want to consider using [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) instead of `.parent().parent()` - it makes the code more stable to DOM structure changes.